# Too many open files AWS

Tags: tomcat, amazon-aws, log

Estou rodando minha aplicação na Amazon, fiz o deploy de uma versão que separa os arquivos de log por tenant e data, isso fez com que em certo momento meu ambiente não aceitasse mais requisições, estourando um erro de IOException.

```
    29-Mar-2016 11:56:07.939 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-Acceptor-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run Socket accept failed
 java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:688)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema com o seguinte tutorial.

https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/